# SQL query to fetch best bid for auction and number of bidders who have submitted that bid

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project where I want to fetch from my postgres database for each auction the best bid (best bid being the bid with least amount) and the number of bidders who have submitted that bid with the least amount.  I am trying to write the query for this.
The schema is as follows -

**Auction Table**

| auction_id (PK) | auction_data |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | a1_data |
| A2 | a2_data |
| A3 | a3_data |

**Bids Table**

| bid_id (PK) | auction_id (FK) | user_id | bid_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | A1 | U1 | P1 |
| B2 | A2 | U1 | P2 |
| B3 | A1 | U2 | P3 |
| B4 | A2 | U2 | P4 |
| B5 | A2 | U3 | P4 |

**The constraint is that for each auction any user can submit only a single bid.**
So if the query is run on the above data the output should be like assuming (P1 > P3 and P2 > P4)-

| auction_id | best_bid_price | best_bid_submitted_times | auction_data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | P3 | 1 | a1_data |
| A2 | P4 | 2 | a2_data |
| A3 | null | null | a3_data |

I have tried the following query to get the best bid value but I am unable to come up with their count in the same query. Any help would be welcome, I am a newbie to SQL and hence struggling to grasp how to write this query.

```
select bidRanks.bid_price, bidRanks.auction_id, bidRanks.auction_data
    from (
        select bids.bid_price, bids.auction_id, auction_auction_data rank() over(partition by bids.auction_id order by bids.bid_price asc) as bidRank
        from auctions left join bids on auction.auction_id = bids.auction_id
    ) as bidRanks where bidRanks.bidRank = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by auction and price to get the counts. Then pick the best price per auction. I am doing this in below query with PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`.

```
selects
  a.auction_id,
  b.bid_price as best_bid_price,
  b.bid_count as best_bid_submitted_times,
  a.auction_data
from auction a
left outer join
(
  select distinct on (auction_id) auction_id, bid_price, count(*) as bid_count
  from bids
  group by auction_id, bid_price
  order by auction_id, bid_price
) b on b.auction_id = a.auction_id
order by a.auction_id;
```

Comment: the last line `order by a.auction_id` is not needed, right? It can be omitted if the ordering of the result does not matter? Also how does `GROUP BY` work with`DISTINCT ON`? Isn't `DISTINCT ON` always supposed to return a single row based on the ordering? How is it able to count the duplicates?

Comment: Correct, the last `ORDER BY` is not needed, if the result order doesn't matter. `GROUP BY` happens first. Then `DISTINCT ON` works on the already aggregated result.

Comment: If the Bids table had another column representing the currency of the bid amount how will the query change then?

Comment: You'd join the bids table with a currency rate table so you can calculate the bid price in some base currency and use this in grouping and for comparision.

Comment: Since this is a nested query it will take more time to execute as compared to a simple one. Can we simplify this to a single `select` statement?

Comment: A more complex query takes of course longer than a simple one. But this is just as complex as the task it solves. So, no, we cannot convert it into a "single" statement. And it is not that nested queries are per se slow. The query, as we write it, just describes what data to get. It is up to the DBMS to find the best execution plan for this. But for this task some steps are necessary. The DBMS cannot avoid doing this step by step. The query is straight-forward, so we shouldn't mess with it. If it's too slow, then consider providing an index to help the DBMS with the task.

Comment: One could consider replacing `COUNT(*)` / `GROUP BY auction_id, bid_price` by `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY auction_id, bid_price)` in order to show the DBMS that we need this per row, so it would suffice to do this for the top row only. But my test shows that this can lead to a worse execution plan even. Anyway, an index could definitely help. Here is my small test: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=1669c467afa6c6a247125cb354a8dc45

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
I'm first getting the least bid price for each auction and then counting them

```
SELECT 
auction_id,
auction_data,
min(bid_price) as best_bid_price,
count(bid_price) as best_bid_submitted_times
FROM (
    select 
    a.auction_id, 
    a.auction_data,
    b.bid_price,
    rank() over (partition by a.auction_id order by b.bid_price asc) as rnk
    from auctions a
    left join bids b
    on (a.auction_id = b.auction_id)) a
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY 
auction_id,
auction_data
```

Alternatively, you can also get the Users (U1/U2...) in the sub query and count the distinct users in the outer query to get `best_bid_submitted_times`